# get nearest matching word from a list of words python

Tags: python

i have a word to match from a list of words.

```
word = 'soffe'

total_list= ['You', 'get', 'three', 'pairs', 'Sophie', 'cheer', 'shorts',
 'size', 'small', 'medium', 'girls', 'two', 'sports', 'bra/boy', 'shorts', 
'spandex', 'matching', 'sets', 'small', 'medium', 'girls.', 'All', 'items', 
'total', 'retail', 'store', 'take', 'today', 'less', 'price', 
'one', 'item', 'store!']
```

i want to find the nearest matching word from this list.

i'e my answer should be **'sophie'**

I used

```
1. **fuzzywords**

 from fuzzywuzzy import process
 process.extract(word, total_list)
 >>>[('store', 60), ('store!', 60), ('Sophie', 55), ('one', 50), ('size', 44)]
```

it gave only 55% to sophie.

```
2. **difflib**

difflib.get_close_matches(word, total_list)
>>> ['store']
```

Both of these packages didn't help me.

Is there any way where i can find the nearest pronounced word,
as soffe and sophie are pronounced similarly.
This is just a thought.

Is there any other way to achieve?

Comment: Maybe try the levenstein distance?

Comment: @jheld the similarities between levenshtein and difflib are great, that's why i didn't try that,

Comment: Try using Soundex follow this [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/soundex) for more information.

Comment: @SRingne So does your preference for "sophie" based on some concept of distance or not?

Comment: @Goyo distance plus pronunciation